# z3 SMT solver performance on different platforms

Tags: concurrency, z3, multicore, smt, z3py

I have logic problems written using z3py. I run them on both my pc (intel core i5 + 8GB RAM) and a cluster (32 AMD Operaton 6320 cpus + 500GB RAM). There is no big difference on the runtime and sometimes the remote server takes longer time which confuses me.
Does anyone have any idea whether z3 solver is more efficient on multi-core machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, Z3 does not make use of multiple cores or CPUs.

It does however, come with the par-or and par-and tactics which can be used to craft custom tactics that make use of parallelism.

Comment: Thanks, Christoph. This is really helpful. But is it possible to use these two tactics in Z3 python api?

Comment: Yes, they are called ParAndThen and ParOr, see here: http://z3prover.github.io/api/html/namespacez3py.html#ab3f56f42a92f895a293dd106ce88076d